# Merge multiple rows into fewest number of rows of distinct values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

In SQL Server does anyone know of a nice way to merge/flatten multiple rows of data into the fewest possible rows containing only the distinct non null values.

I.e.

A dataset like this:
[image: before]

As this:
[image: after]

If it helps, the before dataset is a pivoted line listing but without the aggregate.  I can't aggregate it during the pivot as I want to keep each of the distinct values and not take the MAX or MIN.

The only way I can think of doing it involves splitting the data up and joining it all back together which wont be very efficient.

Comment: I'm having the same thoughts and having a hard time thinking of a way to do this without splitting the data apart too. I can think of ways to make the splitting of the data more performant, but I'm curious to see what someone else can come up with.

Comment: Please post a script to create a sample data set (including indexes) and illustrates the approach you have tried that will not be efficient enough.

Comment: What Geoff said. Also, since the data comes not from a base table but from a query, it would be best if you provided that query. Someone might be able to improve so it produces the final result, combining the 2 complex steps into a (possibly more efficient) 1 step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data appears to lack any relationship between the various column values. If you can define this relationship, you can `PIVOT` the data appropriately.

For example, if you simply want to align the data based on the order of the value (based on your default collation), you could use:

```
with rawdata as (
select * from (values
    ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000037850','Col2','Yes_02')
    ,('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000037850','Col3','Full marketing schedule')
    ,('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000037850','Col3','Negotiations started, fell through')
    ,('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000037850','Col3','No budget')
    ,('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000037850','Col3','Not interest')
    ,('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000037850','Col3','Passed to Summerhouse')
    ,('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000037850','Col4','Darren Waters_01')
    ,('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000037850','Col4','David Edwards_01')
    ,('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000037850','Col4','David Simons_01')
    ,('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000037850','Col4','Jason Gould_01')
    ,('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000037850','Col4','Martin Thorpe_01')
    ,('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000037850','Col5','BETT New Exhibitor')
    ,('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000037850','Col5','BETT Standard Exhibitor')
    ,('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000037850','Col5','Exhibitor Verified')
    ) x ([ID],[Col],[Value])
    ), ordered as (
select
    ID
    ,Col
    ,[Value]
    ,rn = row_number() over (partition by ID, Col order by [Value])
    from rawdata
    )
select
    ID
    ,[Col1],[Col2],[Col3],[Col4],[Col5]
    from ordered o
    pivot(max([Value]) for Col in ([Col1],[Col2],[Col3],[Col4],[Col5])) pvt
    ;
```

Comment: Thank you for this, solved my problem perfectly and was almost exactly the same as my underlying code. I just had to add the row_number() to my solution!

Answer (score 6):

Here are a couple ways you might approach the task by assigning an arbitrary row number to each of the non-NULL values for each column (avoiding extraneous sorts since the problem statement does not require ordered data) and then pivoting the resulting data into your final result set.

**Create test data**

```
CREATE TABLE #table (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    Col1 VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    Col2 VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    Col3 VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    Col4 VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    Col5 VARCHAR(100) NULL
)
GO
INSERT INTO #table (ID, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)
VALUES  (37850, '1A', NULL, '3A', NULL, '5A'),
        (37850, NULL, NULL, '3B', NULL, NULL),
        (37850, NULL, '2A', '3C', '4A', '5B'),
        (37850, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
        (37850, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '5C'),
        (37850, NULL, '2B', NULL, NULL, NULL),
        (37850, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '5D'),
        (37850, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
        (37850, NULL, NULL, NULL, '4B', '5E'),
        (37850, NULL, NULL, NULL, '4C', NULL),
        (37850, NULL, NULL, NULL, '4D', NULL)
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI ON #table (ID)
GO
```

**Perform the desired merge and flatten with one scan of the data per column and only a single sort (or hash group) on the final set of rows**

```
SELECT ID,
        -- Pivot the data for each ID / row number pair,
        MIN(CASE WHEN colNumber = 1 THEN val END) AS Col1,
        MIN(CASE WHEN colNumber = 2 THEN val END) AS Col2,
        MIN(CASE WHEN colNumber = 3 THEN val END) AS Col3,
        MIN(CASE WHEN colNumber = 4 THEN val END) AS Col4,
        MIN(CASE WHEN colNumber = 5 THEN val END) AS Col5
FROM (
    -- Within each ID, assign an arbitrary row number to each non-NULL column value
    SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT 0) ASC) AS rowNum, 1 AS colNumber, Col1 AS val FROM #table WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT 0) ASC) AS rowNum, 2 AS colNumber, Col2 AS val FROM #table WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT 0) ASC) AS rowNum, 3 AS colNumber, Col3 AS val FROM #table WHERE Col3 IS NOT NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT 0) ASC) AS rowNum, 4 AS colNumber, Col4 AS val FROM #table WHERE Col4 IS NOT NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT 0) ASC) AS rowNum, 5 AS colNumber, Col5 AS val FROM #table WHERE Col5 IS NOT NULL
) x
GROUP BY ID, rowNum
GO
```

**In SQL Server 2017+, perform the desired merge and flatten with a single scan over the data and no sorting**

```
SELECT s.ID,
    -- Pivot the data for each ID / row number pair,
    MIN(CASE WHEN v.colNum = 1 THEN v.value END) AS Col1,
    MIN(CASE WHEN v.colNum = 2 THEN v.value END) AS Col2,
    MIN(CASE WHEN v.colNum = 3 THEN v.value END) AS Col3,
    MIN(CASE WHEN v.colNum = 4 THEN v.value END) AS Col4,
    MIN(CASE WHEN v.colNum = 5 THEN v.value END) AS Col5
FROM (
    -- For each ID, build the list of non-NULL values, using
    -- a delimiter that will not exist in your data
    SELECT t.ID,
        STRING_AGG(t.Col1,CHAR(0)) as stringAgg1,
        STRING_AGG(t.Col2,CHAR(0)) as stringAgg2,
        STRING_AGG(t.Col3,CHAR(0)) as stringAgg3,
        STRING_AGG(t.Col4,CHAR(0)) as stringAgg4,
        STRING_AGG(t.Col5,CHAR(0)) as stringAgg5
    FROM #table t
    GROUP BY t.ID
) s
OUTER APPLY (
    -- For each ID, unpivot the list of non-NULL values,
    -- appending an arbitrary row number to each value
    SELECT value, 1 AS colNum, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS rn FROM STRING_SPLIT(s.stringAgg1,CHAR(0)) UNION ALL
    SELECT value, 2 AS colNum, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS rn FROM STRING_SPLIT(s.stringAgg2,CHAR(0)) UNION ALL
    SELECT value, 3 AS colNum, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS rn FROM STRING_SPLIT(s.stringAgg3,CHAR(0)) UNION ALL
    SELECT value, 4 AS colNum, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS rn FROM STRING_SPLIT(s.stringAgg4,CHAR(0)) UNION ALL
    SELECT value, 5 AS colNum, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS rn FROM STRING_SPLIT(s.stringAgg5,CHAR(0))
) v
-- For each ID, group together all column values with same row number
GROUP BY s.ID, v.rn
GO
```

**Visualize the test data**

[image]

**Visualize the results**

[image]